# How to Allow a Site Hosted with Amazon to Be Embedded in an iFrame?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iframe, amazon-s3, x-frame-options

I am fairly inexperienced with AWS so this may be an issue of understanding site structure or intricacies between web hosts.

I used to have a site hosted with HostMonster and was able to allow the site to be referenced from an iFrame on another domain. This was achieved by adding the ALLOW-FROM option to the x-frame-options.

The site was recently moved to AWS. It is using S3, EC2, with Elastic Beanstalk. Now when I try to embed the site I get this error:

> Refused to display 'http://example.com' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Seems obvious that I have to set this option but I am not clear on how to do so.

I found this [forum asking for support for X-Frame-Options](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=149569). A response from AWS support confirms that S3 does not currently support X-Frame-Options.

Does this mean I am out of luck or am I just barking up the wrong tree?

I've also looked into the [aws CORS header setting docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors) and tried allowing the origin I am embedding from and even tried allowing from * to test.

Additionally I and found this [GitHub for making S3 files public](https://gist.github.com/philfreo/3843375). I implemented the policy and configuration they have set there but still get the same error.

If it seems like I've left out anything important please ask me about it. Like I said I'm very new to web development and am still figuring things out.

**Edit:**

As was pointed out it is interesting that a header with X-Frame-Options is being returned at all. Here is the full response I get when I load the page directly.

> Connection:keep-alive
>
> Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
>
> Date:Sun, 19 Jun 2016 00:31:37 GMT
>
> Server:Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.1k-fips mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10
>
> transfer-encoding:chunked
>
> X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN

Comment: You're also doing some guessing.  Don't guess.  `Refused to display 'http://example.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`  Look at the response headers when you load the site, not in an iframe.  This error seems to imply that the header *is* being set, so the first questions are "really?" and "how?"

Comment: Interesting point. I guess that would be good news, meaning that it is supported and I just don't know how to configure it. I've posted the response header as an edit to the original question.

Comment: So, this is EC2, where you can do essentially whatever you need.  The limitation applies only to S3.

Comment: I'm not completely clear on the architecture here. I inherited the site  after another developer configured everything. I can see that we have a few instances running on EC2 but I also see a bucket under S3 with the name of the site.

Comment: @mkatic please let me know where can I apply the change in .ebextensions, I really appreciate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the enable_mod_deflate.conf file in .ebextensions with the setting "Header always unset X-Frame-Options":

**enable_mod_deflate.conf**

```
# mod_deflate configuration
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   # Make surei proxies don't deliver the wrong content
   Header always unset X-Frame-Options  
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: where can I find enable_mod_deflate.conf file

Comment: Where is the .ebextensions?

Comment: I have EC2 but not with Elastic Beanstalk, does it work too?